# New in PHP OOP and need opinion am I doing it the right way

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented, sql

I am new to using PHP OOP and decided to start learning by converting something I wrote in procedural PHP. So now I need your opinion and recommendations for my first work.

One of the main reasons I chose this project, is that it has a lot of repetitive SQL queries, with small differences (like a date interval for example). Using PHP OOP I can write those queries once in my class file and then alter needed values on a case basis. As you can see in the "frontend", I have the same data for the present month and then the same data for the past 6 months.

Here is my code:

class file

```
<?php

namespace SimpleStats;

class SalesRepresentatives
{
    protected $userId = 0;
    protected $startDate = "Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01')";
    protected $endDate = 'CurDate()';
    protected $interval = 0;

    public function returnResponse()
    {
        echo 'this is response';
    }

    /**
     * Get TargetLevel
     */
    public function getTargetLevel()
    {
        $sql = 'Select ';
        $sql .= 'ue.fk_object, ';
        $sql .= 'ue.perstargetqty, ';
        $sql .= 'ue.perstargetcust ';
        $sql .= 'From ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user_extrafields ue ';
        $sql .= 'WHERE ';
        $sql .= 'ue.fk_object=' . $this->userId . '';

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Set TargetLevel
     */
    public function setTargetLevel($userId)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * Get NewCustomer
     */
    public function getNewCustomer()
    {
        $sql = 'Select ';
        $sql .= 'Count(s.rowid) As count_rowid ';
        $sql .= 'From ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe s Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc On s.rowid = sc.fk_soc Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u On sc.fk_user = u.rowid ';
        $sql .= 'Where ';
        $sql .= "CAST(s.datec As Date) Between $this->startDate And $this->endDate And ";
        $sql .= 'u.rowid = "' . $this->userId . '" ';

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Set NewCustomer
     */
    public function setNewCustomer($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get QTY sold
     */
    public function getQtySold()
    {
        $sql = 'Select ';
        $sql .= 'COALESCE(Sum(fd.qty), 0) As qty_sum ';
        $sql .= 'From ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facturedet fd Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facture f On fd.fk_facture = f.rowid Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc On sc.fk_soc = f.fk_soc Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u On sc.fk_user = u.rowid ';
        $sql .= 'Where ';
        $sql .= "f.datef Between $this->startDate And $this->endDate And ";
        $sql .= 'u.rowid = "' . $this->userId . '" ';

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Set QTY sold
     */
    public function setQtySold($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get Turnover
     */
    public function getTurnover()
    {
        $sql = 'Select ';
        $sql .= 'Sum(f.total) As total_sum ';
        $sql .= 'From ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facture f Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc On sc.fk_soc = f.fk_soc Inner Join ';
        $sql .= '' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u On sc.fk_user = u.rowid ';
        $sql .= 'Where ';
        $sql .= "f.datef Between $this->startDate And $this->endDate And ";
        $sql .= 'u.rowid = "' . $this->userId . '"';

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Set Turnover
     */
    public function setTurnover($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get Clients without invoices
     */
    public function getClientWoInvoice()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT Max(f.datef) As max_datef, s.rowid, f.fk_soc, s.nom, s.phone, s.email, f.datef, sc.fk_soc, sc.fk_user, u.rowid, u.firstname, u.lastname ';
        $sql .= 'FROM ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe s ';
        $sql .= 'INNER JOIN ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc ON s.rowid = sc.fk_soc ';
        $sql .= 'AND sc.fk_user="' . $this->userId . '" ';
        $sql .= 'INNER JOIN ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u ON sc.fk_user = u.rowid ';
        $sql .= 'INNER JOIN ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facture f ON s.rowid = f.fk_soc ';
        $sql .= 'GROUP BY f.fk_soc ';
        $sql .= 'HAVING ';
        $sql .= "MAX(f.datef) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL $this->interval DAY";

        return $sql;
    }

    /**
     * Set Clients without invoices
     */
    public function setClientWoInvoice($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

and frontend file:

```
<?php

// Security check
//if (! $user->rights->simplestats->myobject->read) accessforbidden();
$socid = GETPOST('socid', 'int');
if (isset($user->socid) && $user->socid > 0) {
    $action = '';
    $socid  = $user->socid;
}

$max = 5;
$now = dol_now();


/*
 * View
 */

$form     = new Form($db);
$formfile = new FormFile($db);

//Define module parameters
$dlo      = $conf->global->DaysLastOrder == '' ? '30' : $conf->global->DaysLastOrder;
$datetype = $conf->global->DateType == '' ? 'd-m-Y' : $conf->global->DateType;
$months   = $conf->global->HowManyMonths == '' ? '6' : $conf->global->HowManyMonths;

llxHeader("", $langs->trans("SalesStats"));

print load_fiche_titre($langs->trans("SalesStats"), '', 'sales.png@simplestats');
?>

<div class="fichecenter">
    <div class="fichethirdleft">

        <!-- START STATISTICS FOR THIS MONTH  -->
        <div class="inline-block floatleft titre">
            <?php print $langs->trans('PersTarget') . ' ' . date('m.Y'); ?>
        </div>
        <hr><br>

        <?php

        //Get target level
        $object = new SimpleStats\SalesRepresentatives();

        $object->setTargetLevel($user->id);
        $resql = $db->query($object->getTargetLevel()) or die($db->error);

        if (!$resql) {
            dol_print_error($db);
        }

        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();
        $ptarqty = $conf->global->{"TargetQty" . $row['perstargetqty']};
        $ptarcust = $conf->global->{"TargetThirdParty" . $row['perstargetcust']};

        //Get New Thirdparties for this month
        $resql = $db->query($object->getNewCustomer()) or die($db->error);

        if (!$resql) {
            dol_print_error($db);
        }
        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();
        $count_recall = $row['count_rowid'] + 0;

        if ($ptarcust != 0) {
            print '' . $langs->trans('NewCustomers') . ': ' . $count_recall . '/' . $ptarcust . '';
            $percent1 = ($row['count_rowid'] / $ptarcust) * 100;
            print '<div class="barcontainer"><div class="barskill" style="width: ' . $percent1 . '%;">
            ' . $percent1 . '%</div></div><br>';
        } else {
            print '' . $langs->trans('NewCustomers') . ': ' . $langs->trans('NoTarget') . '<br><br>';
        }

        //Get QTY sold and comission for this month
        $resql = $db->query($object->getQtySold()) or die($db->error);

        if (!$resql) {
            dol_print_error($db);
        }
        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();

        $qty_recall = $row['qty_sum'] + 0;

        if ($ptarqty != 0) {
            print '' . $langs->trans("SoldQty") . ': ' . $qty_recall . '/' . $ptarqty . '';
            $percent2 = ($row['qty_sum'] / $ptarqty) * 100;
            print '<div class="barcontainer">
                <div class="barskill" style="width: ' . $percent2 . '%;">' . $percent2 . '%</div></div><br>';
        } else {
            print '' . $langs->trans("SoldQty") . ': ' . $langs->trans("NoTarget") . '<br><br>';
        }
        ?>

        <div class='div-table-responsive'>
            <table width='100%' class='tagtable liste listwithfilterbefore'>
                <thead>
                    <th class='center nowrap'>
                        <?php
                        print '' . $langs->trans('Comission') . ' ' . $langs->trans('for') . ' ' . date('m.Y') . '';
                        ?>
                    </th>
                    <th class='center nowrap'>
                        <?php
                        print '' . $langs->trans('Turnover') . ' ' . $langs->trans('for') . ' ' . date('m.Y') . '';
                        ?>
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php
                    $comission = $row['qty_sum'] * $conf->global->PerQty;
                    print '<tr class="oddeven"><td class="center nowrap">
                                ' . price(round($comission, 2), 1, $langs, 1, -1, -1, $conf->currency) . '
                            </td>';

                    // Get Turnover for this month
                    $resql = $db->query($object->getTurnover()) or die($db->error);

                    if (!$resql) {
                        dol_print_error($db);
                    }

                    $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();

                    print '<td class="center nowrap">
                                ' . price($row['total_sum'], 1, $langs, 1, -1, -1, $conf->currency) . '
                            </td></tr>';
                    ?>
                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END STATISTICS FOR THIS MONTH  -->

        <!-- START STATISTICS FOR PAST 6 MONTHS  -->

        <div class="inline-block floatleft titre">
            <?php print '' . $langs->trans("PersTargetPast") . ' ' . $months . ' ' . $langs->trans("months") . '' ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <br><em><small><?php print '' . $langs->trans('sorting') . '' ?></small></em><br>
        <div class='div-table-responsive'>
            <table width='100%' class='tagtable liste listwithfilterbefore sortable'>
                <thead>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('Month') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('NewCustomers') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('Compl') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('SoldQty') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('Compl') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('Comission') ?></th>
                    <th class="center"><?php print $langs->trans('Turnover') ?></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php
                    for ($i = 1; $i < ($months + 1); $i++) {
                        $date = date('Y-m', strtotime("-$i month"));
                        print '<tr class="oddeven">';
                        print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $date . '</td>';

                        //Get New ThirdParty for past 6 months
                        $object->setNewCustomer('startDate', "'" . $date . "-01'");
                        $object->setNewCustomer('endDate', "'" . $date . "-31'");

                        $resql = $db->query($object->getNewCustomer()) or die($db->error);
                        if (!$resql) {
                            dol_print_error($db);
                        }
                        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();
                        $count_recall2 = $row['count_rowid'] + 0;

                        if ($ptarcust != 0) {
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $count_recall2 . '</td>';
                            $percent3 = ($count / $ptarcust) * 100;
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $percent3 . '%</td>';
                        } else {
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $count_recall2 . '</td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">0%</td>';
                        }

                        //Get QTY sold for past 6 months
                        $object->setQtySold('startDate', "'" . $date . "-01'");
                        $object->setQtySold('endDate', "'" . $date . "-31'");

                        $resql = $db->query($object->getQtySold()) or die($db->error);
                        if (!$resql) {
                            dol_print_error($db);
                        }
                        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();

                        if ($ptarqty != 0) {
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $row['qty_sum'] . '</td>';
                            $percent4 = ($row['qty_sum'] / $ptarqty) * 100;
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $percent4 . '%</td>';
                            $comission2 = $row['qty_sum'] * $conf->global->PerQty;
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">
                            ' . price(round($comission2, 2), 1, $langs, 1, -1, -1, $conf->currency) . '</td>';
                        } else {
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $row['qty_sum'] . '</td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">0%</td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">
                            ' . price(round($comission2, 2), 1, $langs, 1, -1, -1, $conf->currency) . '</td>';
                        }

                        //Get Turnover for past 6 months
                        $object->setTurnover('startDate', "'" . $date . "-01'");
                        $object->setTurnover('endDate', "'" . $date . "-31'");

                        $resql = $db->query($object->getTurnover()) or die($db->error);
                        if (!$resql) {
                            dol_print_error($db);
                        }
                        $row = $resql->fetch_assoc();

                        print '<td class="center nowrap">
                            ' . price($row['total_sum'], 1, $langs, 1, -1, -1, $conf->currency) . '
                        </td></tr>';
                    }
                    ?>

                <tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- END STATISTICS FOR PAST 6 MONTHS  -->

    </div>

    <div class="fichetwothirdright">

        <div class="ficheaddleft">

            <!-- START CLIENTS WITHOUT INVOICES -->
            <div class="titre inline-block">
                <?php
                print '' . $langs->trans('ClNoOrder') . ' ';
                print '' . $langs->trans('for') . ' ';
                print '' . $langs->trans('last') . ' ';
                print $dlo;
                print ' ' . $langs->trans('days') . '';
                ?>
                <br>
                <em><small><?php print $langs->trans('Searchterm4'); ?></small></em>
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <?php
            $object->setClientWoInvoice('interval', "' . $db->escape($dlo) . '");
            $resql = $db->query($object->getClientWoInvoice()) or die($db->error);
            if (!$resql) {
                dol_print_error($db);
            }
            ?>

            <br>
            <em><small><?php print $langs->trans('sorting'); ?></small></em>
            <br>
            <div class='div-table-responsive'>
                <table width='100%' class='tagtable liste listwithfilterbefore sortable'>
                    <thead>
                        <th class="center" id="cln"><?php print $langs->trans('ClName'); ?></th>
                        <th class="center" id="pho"><?php print $langs->trans('Phone'); ?></th>
                        <th class="center" id="ema"><?php print $langs->trans('Email'); ?></th>
                        <th class="center" id="lid"><?php print $langs->trans('LastInvDate'); ?></th>
                        <th class="center" id="btn"><?php print $langs->trans('Call'); ?></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = $resql->fetch_assoc()) {
                            print '<tr>';
                            print '<td class="left nowrap"><a href="' . DOL_URL_ROOT . '/societe/card.php?socid=
                                ' . $row['fk_soc'] . '" target="_blank">' . $row["nom"] . '</a></td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">
                                        <a href="mailto:' . $row['email'] . '">' . $row['email'] . '</a>
                                    </td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">
                                    ' . date('' . $datetype . '', strtotime($row['max_datef'])) . '
                                    </td>';
                            print '<td class="center nowrap">
                                    <a class="butAction"
                                        href="tel:' . $row['phone'] . '">' . $langs->trans('Call') . '</a>
                                    </td>';
                            print '</tr>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- END CLIENTS WITHOUT INVOICES -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
llxFooter();
$db->close();
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `'' . print` looks rather curious.  Who taught you that? How ancient is this code, if you don't mind me asking?  I am sorry, but this code is so far away from professional grade that I do not have the time to give a comprehensive review that meets my own quality standards.

Comment: @mickmackusa , my typo. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 6):

I'll focus on `SalesRepresentatives` class, because that seems to be your main concern.

## Documentation

There is none. Note that "Get TargetLevel" for a function named `getTargetLevel()` doesn't add anything.

## Getter/Setter Asymmetry

I'd expect `getTargetLevel()` to give me what I previously set using `setTargetLevel()`. That is very surprising behaviour.

## Protected

`protected` means that you explicity make something available to derived classes. This basically implies that you have a plan how derived classes are supposed to use those protected fields. This needs a few words (documentation) to instruct the authors of the derived classes as well.

## Type Annotations

There are none. They are available in both PHP7 and PHP8, so use them!

## `MAIN_DB_PREFIX` Constant

You could inject that prefix into this class through a constructor. This dependency on globals makes the code harder to test against a dummy table.

## Proposed Change

Here's a sketch of a change to this class:

```
/** utility to create SQL queries from templates */
class SqlQueryFactory
{
    private string $prefix;

    public function __construct(string $prefix)
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function createTargetLevelQuery(int $userId): string
    {
        return 'Select '
             . 'ue.fk_object, '
             . 'ue.perstargetqty, '
             . 'ue.perstargetcust '
             . 'From '
             . $this->prefix . 'user_extrafields ue '
             . 'WHERE '
             . 'ue.fk_object=' . $userId
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I renamed the class so that even without reading it, you get an idea of what it does.
- There are no setters. The required parameters for a formatting operation are not set as members but passed as parameters.
- I annotated `$prefix`, `$userId` and the returnvalue with types. Note that the support for those annotations evolved in the PHP 7 series a lot, the above requires 7.4.
- There is no getter, because there is no target level attribute either. Instead, "create target level query" now describes that it creates a (SQL-) query.
- Just a minor nitpick: I merged the formatting operation into one statement, it simply requires less typing.
- **DANGER**: This code, just like your original code, is prone to "SQL injections". Please take a short timeout from your task and read a bit about that topic. Preferably, switch to using PHP's PDO which allows you fill fields in templates even from variables who's content can not be trusted.

Comment: thanks for your comment. As I said, my goal is to reduce the code in my files a lot. For example, I can have the same SQL query  (let's say the one in `getQtySold()` ) on 10 different places, and the differences are the userID and date period. So, in my files, i use `$object->setQtySold('name', 'value')` . As for the rest, when I have an SQL query what annotation should I include? For the variables inside the query or what? And by Documentation - to say what variables are indented for?

Comment: You can use `public function setFoo(int $foo): void { ... }` when declaring a function. Those are type annotations. You can also document them `@param string $foo` and `@return void` in a docblock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very helpful . As for the sql injection, this is an add on for third-party software, so when using $this->db there are escapes implemented. Also, I use $this->db->escape($somevar) when I am inserting variables from user input fields into sql queries.